# The preposition with the word "value"?

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct way of writing?

- He bought 50 shares `with` the nominal value of ... (sum of money)
- He bought 50 shares `of` the nominal value of ...
- He bought 50 shares `for` the nominal value of ...
- He bought 50 shares `having a` nominal value of ...

Answer (score 2):

*With*, *at*, or *having* would be correct here.  But, their meaning is subtly different in each.

*With* or *having* means the shares are valued at x.

*At* means the shares were valued at x when he bought them.

*For* means the price he paid for them which as WS2 points out in comments might be different from the nominal price.

Note that all of these differences are really subtle, and no one would really be confused if you used them interchangeably.

*Of* doesn't really work here.  It makes it sound like:  He is buying 50 shares of a stock called *the nominal value of . . .*

Comment: As they are 'nominal' values, the said value will not fluctuate. It is the 'market value' which moves. 'Nominal' is the value at which they are recorded in the company's books, which does not change (unless they are shares at no par value, but that's an unnecessary complication here). I would use, 'with' or 'having', but I would not use 'at' or 'for'. They both suggest it was the price paid, which might be quite different to the 'nominal value'.

Comment: @WS2 that is a reasonable statement.

Comment: Indeed, the value is not meant to change.Thank you both very much. Now I understand the differences between those prepositions much better.